# If statement in sort by clause causing timeout

Tags: sql, mysql

I am running a pretty basic select statement in sql joining a couple tables together. It runs just fine when I exclude the "ORDER BY" clause completing in ms. However when I add the "ORDER BY" since the tables have millions of results the query times out. Any suggestions on how to fix this so to optimize performance?

```
ORDER  BY IF(table1.name IS NULL
              OR table1.name = '', table2.uuid,
          table1.name),
          table2.uuid
```

Ive removed the order by and just sorted on the table2.uuid which improved performance and ran the query in ms. I would like to hopefully sort by table1.name and keep the functionality but improve the way its done if possible.

Comment: maybe `case when coalesce(table1.name,'') = '' then table2.uuid else table1.name end`  I find ors to be very slow or perhaps add a stored [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) whihc retains this value so it does'nt have to be computed each time for all records; but instead once on insert/update.  Generated columns are similar in concept to that of computed columns in SQL server.  I'm not sure if mySQL supports function based indexes but that may be an approach as well.

Comment: Trying this out to see how it improves performance and it decreases run time from 18 minutes to 2.5 which for me is great but sadly not enough.

Comment: I'd consider the generated (and stored) olumn then.  So the values are stored in a column which you can then just order by.  the values are "computed" in advance and update as needed when the columns change.  are you sure table1.name has both nulls and empty set?  or is it just nulls? could we do `coalesce(table1.name, table2.name)` to take the first non-null value?

Comment: for performance questions, please include (as text, not images) output of `show create table yourtablename` for all tables referenced in the query, and the full query, and output of `explain select ...rest of your query` for all the variants in question (here the one without order by and the one with)

Comment: It's nearly impossible to optimize ordering by a computed value like this. If UUID is indexed, ordering by that can use the index. But when you add the condition, it has to save all the results first, then do a slow sort of the data.

Comment: Let's see the whole query.

Comment: I ended up removing the order by if statement altogether if the query didn't have another specific WHERE statement.

Answer (score 1):

**Indexing**: Ensure that the columns used in your ORDER BY clause are indexed. Indexing can significantly speed up sorting operations. In your case, consider indexing the columns used in the IF condition and the table2.uuid column.

```
sql
CREATE INDEX idx_table1_name ON table1(name);
CREATE INDEX idx_table2_uuid ON table2(uuid);
```

**Optimize ORDER BY Clause:** If possible, simplify the ORDER BY clause. In your case, you might try to avoid using functions like IF directly in the ORDER BY clause. Instead, you can use a CASE statement:

```
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN table1.name IS NULL OR table1.name = '' THEN table2.uuid
        ELSE table1.name
    END,
    table2.uuid;
```

Comment: Thank you this was helpful. I didn't know you could add a case statement in ORDER BY clause but I decided to just order by table2.uuid